# Как получить картинку из бинарного кода?

Tags: javascript, jquery, изображения, img, binary

У меня есть БД, я храню там картинки в бинарном виде. Моя html страница принимает с помощью ajax этот бинарный код картинки. Как этот бинарный код превратить в картинку что бы можно было вывести её в img?

Answer (score 3):

### Первый вариант:

Если есть желание использовать `$.ajax`

**html: элемент на странице**

```
<img id="image" />
```

**js: добавляем [binary транспорт](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport)**

```
(function($) {
    $.ajaxTransport("+binary", function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (window.FormData && ((options.dataType && (options.dataType == 'binary')) || (options.data && ((window.ArrayBuffer && options.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) || (window.Blob && options.data instanceof Blob))))) {
            return {
                send: function(headers, callback) {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
                        url = options.url,
                        type = options.type,
                        async = options.async || true,
                        dataType = options.responseType || "blob",
                        data = options.data || null,
                        username = options.username || null,
                        password = options.password || null;
                    xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
                        var data = {};
                        data[options.dataType] = xhr.response;
                        callback(xhr.status, xhr.statusText, data, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    });
                    xhr.addEventListener('error', function() {
                        var data = {};
                        data[options.dataType] = xhr.response;
                        callback(xhr.status, xhr.statusText, data, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    });
                    xhr.open(type, url, async, username, password);
                    for (var i in headers) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(i, headers[i]);
                    }
                    xhr.responseType = dataType;
                    xhr.send(data);
                },
                abort: function() {}
            };
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**js: получение картинки**

```
$.ajax({
    url : "image?id=1",
    type : "GET",
    dataType : 'binary',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'image/png',
        'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    processData : false,
    success : function (data) {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        $("#image").attr("src", url);
    }
});
```

Где  `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` копирует массив байт в память и создает ссылку.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/L760yqmy/1/)

Если не нужен jquery то можно сделать так:

**js**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", "image?id=1", true );
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function( e ) {
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    var img = document.querySelector( "#image" );
    img.src = imageUrl;
};
xhr.send();
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/8e5znhz0/)

### Второй вариант:

Если сервер возвращает правильные заголовки например: `Content-Type: image/png`, то можно сделать так:

**html:**

```
<img src="image?id=1" />
```

Это должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну способов не так уж и много
Я бы предложил `btoa`, который способен из бинарника сделать base64 , которую потом легко подключить и получить картинку [Тык](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Хотя в любом случае смотрите в сторону base64 - есть много способов приводить разные типы к base64.